# Numerical Algorithm for $n \times n$ Matrix Inverse

Tags: matrices, inverse

I have to write a C program in which I have to compute the matrix inverse of a $n \times n$ matrix. Is there a convenient iterative process that I can use to do that? All I see is the co factor method or the row operations method.

Is there a method that will be convenient to implement for matrix inverse?

Comment: http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2012/134653/

Comment: Note that you need to have a very good reason to compute explicitly the inverse of a matrix (my experience in numerical mathematics is that this is **THE** thing to avoid). Anyway, if you need to solve a linear system, you shouldn't compute the inverse of the matrix if you want speed and efficiency.

Comment: With some clever programming, you can define the row-operation method recursively.

Comment: Agree with Surb.  Also, speed might be one worry, but finding the inverse of a matrix can be numerically unstable.  It is more likely that your application has an implementation that will allow you to circumvent this instability, or at least detect it.

Comment: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/19628/282

Comment: For a first attempt, I recommend LU factorization with partial pivoting.

Comment: Why does every one say that matrix inverse should be avoided ? Then how would you solve equations or problems that require the inverse of the matrix ? What is the alternative ?

Comment: What are the properties of the matrices you are dealing with? Is it guaranteed to be invertible or are you looking for some kind of least-squares fit/pseudo-inverse? Is the matrix maybe positive definite? Do you really need the inverse or is the solution of a linear system $A x = b$ sufficient? This is a good overview of various approaches: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicLinearAlgebraDecompositions.html

Comment: @Yes it guaranteed to be invertible.